# How to get appended accodian in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I get companies from firebase database and append it to html using javascript. This is the code.

```
function loadcompanies() {
    var leadsRef = database.ref('companies');
    leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();

                content +=   '<tr class="header" class="clickable">';
                //content +=    '<tr class="header">';
                content +=  '<td style="width: 55px; color: #42957F">'+childData.rooms+'</td>';
                content +=  '<td id="companyName" onclick="getrooms(this)"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion1" style="width: 102px; font-weight: bold">'+childData.company+'</td>';
                content +=  '<td style="width: 60px;">'+childData.code+'</td>';
                content +=  '<td><a href="#" style="font-size:18px;" onclick="addroom(this)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle plus"></i></a>Add Rooms';
                content +=  '</td>';
                content +=  '</tr>';

                //companyName.innerHTML += '<div>'+childData.company+'</div>';
                //document.getElementById("companyName").innerHTML = childData.company;

                //alert(childData.company);
                console.log(childData.rooms.length);
            });
            $('#abctable').append(content);
        }
    });
}
```

When I load the page and click one of the companies, I get the name of that company using the id `#companyform` in javascript and by using that id I again use the firebase and get its rooms. This is the code.

```
function getrooms(x) {
    name = $(x).closest('tr').find('#companyName').text();
    //var rowIndex = $(x).closest('tr').index();
    var leadsRef= database.ref('companies/' + name + '/nrooms');
    leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            var content= '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(Snapshot){
                var childData= Snapshot.val();
                var key = Snapshot.key;
                content+=  '<tr style="background-color: #F2F2F2; color: #42957F">';
                content+=  '<td style="background-color: none" id="accordion1" class="collapse"></td>';
                content+=  '<td id="accordion1" class="collapse"></td>';
                content+=  '<td id="accordion1" class="collapse"></td>';
                content+=  '<td style="width: 170px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+key+'</td>';
                content+=  ' <td style="width: 250px; font-size: 13px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.roombeacon.uuid+'</td>';
                content+=  '<td style="width: 90px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.roombeacon.major+'</td>';
                content+=  ' <td style="width: 100px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.roombeacon.minor+'</td>';
                content+=  ' <td style="width: 110px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.roombeacon.enter+'</td>';
                content+=  ' <td style="width: 85px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.roombeacon.docking+'</td>';
                content+=  '<td style="width: 45px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.roombeacon.tx+'</td>';
                content+=  '  <td style="font-size: 13px; width: 195px; margin-left:50px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.dockbeacon.uuid+'</td>';
                content+=  '   <td style=" width: 80px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.dockbeacon.major+'</td>';
                content+=  '   <td style="width: 110px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.dockbeacon.minor+'</td>';
                content+=  '   <td style="width: 110px;" id="accordion1" class="collapse">'+childData.dockbeacon.tx+'</td>';
                content+=  ' </tr>';
                console.log(childData.roombeacon.length);
                console.log(childData);
            });
            $('#abctable').append(content);
        }
    });
    // alert(name);
}
```

The problem is that this program I have written is not correctly working, like every room is not loading after the company. It is printing at the end of all the companies listen, and when I click the company multiple times it does not close the according and keep on printing the value from database.

[image: output]
This is what it gives me when i click `Devstop`, It should print after Devstop row. and on clicking Devstop multiple times it is printing the rows multiple times,

Answer (score 1):

I guess the root cause is the duplicated id property shared across your HTML.

Take following as an example, every element in your loop shares the same **id** property, which leads to your undesired result.

```
 forEach{
          <td id="companyName">
 }


   forEach{


      <td id="accordion1">
  }
```

Above is nested in a forEach loop, so elements sharing the same id are produced.

HTML doesn't allow more than one element assigned with the same id.

### Your code has too many errors like this.

I hope following code sample will enlighten you a little bit and you can differentiate every id by appending the current loop index to it.

```
var content = "";
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot, index) {
  content += '<td id="companyName' + index + '">';
});
```

Comment: i know this code has errors, that is why i posted it on here.

Comment: Please make sure that in your for loop, any element you are going to set id property be set with a unique id, then everything will work fine.

Comment: how to do that? how can i set different id's in foreach?

Comment: Updated the answer